# cross browser nowrap textarea

Tags: css, html, cross-browser, textarea

I'm looking for a cross browser solution that makes
textarea :

- wrap text **only** on enter
- scrollbars both hidden, until text overflows

I have tried almost everything can be found in SO...

Failed #1:

```
textarea{
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

does not work in FF

Failed #2:

```
textarea{
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow: auto; // or scroll
}
+WRAP=OFF attribute
```

here I cant hit enter in IE ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GqsTL/))

Failed #3:

```
textarea{
  white-space:pre;
  overflow: auto;
}
+WRAP=OFF attribute
```

auto line break in IE if I reaches the end

Comment: @oshikryu Point in your private site. Here we want to see short question - short answer. We do not want the piles of garbage here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All I did was remove your `white-space: nowrap;` and it works :).

```css
textarea{
overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<textarea wrap="off">
Lorem asldm,és améld masémd éasmdá qw3őri2ő3pjm powemfnsd f
dsf lsdmflkms dlkfmsldk mflksdmfk lmsklf
</textarea>
```

Comment: @2astalavista Whoop! I was about to comment and say you must have something missing that the fiddle includes :)

Answer (score 6):

```
<textarea wrap="off"><textarea>
```

Comment: This works in Internet Explorer 4.0 (just tested on VM for fun).

Comment: In 2020 this is the only answer that produced the expected results for me

Answer (score 1):

You should try `white-space: pre;`

```css
textarea{
  white-space: pre;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px
}
```

```html
<textarea>
Hello World!
Happy New Year Stack Overflow!!
    With Indent
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
overflow-wrap: normal;
```

Just change the overflow parameter for wrap to normal.