# Avoid line returns on textarea text

Tags: html, css, textarea

I am having an issue with the text in my `<textarea>` tag. Here is the matter :

My web app is a html page which write text on textarea on button click. When you click on this button, here is what the `<textarea>` shows :

[image]

As you can see, I underlined in red the matter. My `<textarea>` get some css propreties (see below) that display the 2 scrollbars. I though the text would not return in a new line even with a width (which is `100%` because it is contained in a `table-cell`).

**QUESTION :** How can I avoid this behaviour, which means how can the text stay in one line no matter its length, to allow user to use `bottom-scroll` to see hidden characters ?

Html code of the textarea :

```
<table>
    <!-- some rows and cells -->
    <tr>
        <td id = "content_form_HTMLgenerated" colspan = "6">
            <textarea id = "content_form_HTMLgenerated_textarea"></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Style for the textarea :

```
#content_form_HTMLgenerated {

}

#content_form_HTMLgenerated_textarea {
    width               : 100%;
    height              : 400px;
    resize              : none;
    border              : solid 1px rgba(0, 180, 255, 0.5);
    padding             : 10px;
    overflow-y          : scroll;
    overflow-x          : scroll;
    white-space         : nowrap;
}
```

**N.B.:** I use `colspan = "6"` because I have a table which contains rows getting up to 6 cells.

**N.B.2:** Browser : FireFox 31.4.0

Comment: Your code works, look at that fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dyvwfp2o/. I guess something further down in the css file is overriding your code.

Comment: Thank you for replying @ByteHamster. I tried your JSFiddle by copy/pasting the content of my textArea (a simple html code) in your Fiddle but always the same issue, every line are returned and bottom scroll bar isn't "active" (FireFox 31.4.0)

Comment: Okay, seems to be a Firefox issue. Working fine in Chrome, Internet Explorer and Opera.

Comment: Thank you @ByteHamster for this detail. I am reconsidering using textarea for such a process, maybe some rich text editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to add HTML attribute   `wrap="off"` in `textarea` and add `overflow:auto` .

**Check here**

HTML

```
<table>
    <!-- some rows and cells -->
    <tr>
        <td id="content_form_HTMLgenerated" colspan="6">
            <textarea wrap="off" id="content_form_HTMLgenerated_textarea"></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
#content_form_HTMLgenerated_textarea {
    width : 100%;
    height : 80px;
    resize : none;
    border : solid 1px rgba(0, 180, 255, 0.5);
    padding : 10px;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space : nowrap;
}
```

View in [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bu5oL1rf/4/)

Also refer to [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14443262/cross-browser-nowrap-textarea).